# How to change the kernel commandline for ArchLinuxARM on Raspberry Pi effectly?

Tags: boot, kernel, cmdline.txt, debug

I'm using the raspberry pi with the latest ArchLinuxARM image.

I'm having issues with the linux kernel and it randomly panics with 'kernel paging request' errors.

I've found a solution to enable slub debugging in the linxu kernel [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/24121/6441) and [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=55370) which tells me to edit `/boot/cmdline.txt` and add `slub_debug=FP` at the end of the command line.

I did that but the issue persists and I keep getting kernel panics. Now, other people having that issue report the slub debug option fixed their kernal panic behaviour. They are basicly using debian derivates on their pi.

Now I wonder if the `/boot/cmdline.txt` is the correct way to change the arch linux kernel command line in ArchLinux?

Any ideas what else I could try?

Comment: `/boot/cmdline.txt` should be the correct file. Check the settings have taken effect though by running `cat /proc/cmdline`.

Comment: Do you overclock?

Comment: @avra No, I'm using default clocking. I didnt change the settings at all, why?

Comment: @vertoe: Because with overclocking some problems look like yours. If you are sure that Pi never goes over default 700MHz then it's something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `/boot/cmdline.txt` gets read correctly and can be verified by checking:

```
cat /proc/cmdline
```